# Blog post with image Django3

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hi i'm trying to add some funcionality to my blog post app, i'd like to paste image into post content so i figured is this waw that ive created new model just for images and set it as OneToOne with my Post model
i wonder if ther is any way to set this image to content field in the post model

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content = models.TextField()
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to='post_pics', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height > 500 or img.width > 500:
        output_size = (500, 500)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

**vievs.py**

```
def home(request):
context = {
    'posts': Post.objects.all(),
    'user_posts': "active",
}

return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
```

**post_template.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
   <div class="content-section">
       <form method="POST">
           {% csrf_token %}
           <fieldset class="form-group">
               <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Blog Post</legend>
            {{form|crispy }}
           </fieldset>
           <div class="form-group">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
           </div>
       </form>
   </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pillow
```

& in static/post_pics (see the img.jpg ...png  ) it's save ?

Comment: i want to see if it's save or not !

Comment: Yes its save but i don't kniw how to view this in my post content since i'm using CBV and i don't have any form or template where i could manualy paste this img into content i have all settings configured cuz i have profile pictures for different users

Answer (score 0):

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

[image: in this picture you can see image that i've browsed from my desktop ans it's exactly there where i want it to be saved]

Answer (score 0):

Well i've found another solution i've used CKEditor and now everything works fine